# how to write a simple PHP fiddle to execute php code safely

Tags: php

I want to write a simple PHP fiddle for a programming tutorials website

Similar to [Code Academy](http://www.codeacademy.com) website

**Example**
[Code Academy PHP Fiddle Example](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/1?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8)

I thought of using Code Mirror as a text editor

But **How I could execute the PHP Code that the user write safely ??**

I tried to use file_put_contents() and file_get_contents in their editor

And it works :) is it safe !!

I can't use extensions like [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)
because I am on a shared hosting :(

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't. You need a sandbox of some sort, which will take far more systems access than you'll get on shared hosting. You would need to set up your own host with your own sandboxed PHP executables in order to achieve this.

As you have it there, it is absolutely not safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way is to edit PHP sources and remove the most dangerous functions, compile this and run this new PHP environment from the real PHP.

Parsing the user input and sending to `eval` is in my opinion a security hole. You wouldn't be able to detect dangerous statements like

```
$a = 'ma';
$a .= 'il';
{$a}(...);
```

etc.